# Не работает файл 404.php в созданной теме Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Учу wordpress по видеокурсу (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URFhyvZTENc&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=2), сейчас создаю новую тему с нуля. Использую Open Server, в папку с пустой темой поместил файл style.css с нужным комментарием и index.php. При переходе на главную страницу сайта (http://academy) все работает хорошо, корректно отображается файл index.php. Однако, если ввести URL какой-нибудь несуществующей страницы (например, http://academy/portfolio.php), перекидывает на браузерную страницу ошибки 404, а не на файл index.php, как было сказано в уроке (тайминг видео по ссылке выше 17:10). Файл 404.php, который я впоследствии создал в папке с темой, вообще игнорируется: ввожу ли я URL несуществующей страницы или прямо указываю на этот файл (http://academy/404.php), он никак не хочет открываться. С чем это может быть связано, в чем заключается проблема? Или все работает правильно, и я просто неправильно понял автора видеоурока?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: @KAGGDesign, большое спасибо за данные материалы, я разобрался в редиректах через этот файл, но не могу понять, почему все-таки сервер не видит ни один файл, кроме index.php, которые лежат в папке с темой? Я сделал редирект со страницы с 404 ошибкой на страницу 404.php, которая лежит в папке с темой, теперь если перейти на несуществующую страницу, происходит бесконечная переадресация, ведь файл 404.php, по мнению сервера, тоже отсутствует...

Comment: У вас не работает, потому что нужен .htaccess в корне сайта с содержимым Basic WP из статьи по ссылке. Вот никаких своих выкрутасов, один в один содержимое Basic WP.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, еще раз спасибо, в особенности за терпение! Все работает ^_^